# How to slice a 2D gameObject in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to game development and actually it is a new hobby of mine. I have an interesting game idea related to slicing objects (the base level would require to slice a circle into several places).

However, the thing is that slicing objects **dynamically seems very difficult.** I could not find any tutorials and I did find a [library](https://github.com/DavidArayan/ezy-slice), which seems legit. The problem is, that the library supports only 3D.  Are there any solutions, which would achieve my desired behavior easier?

Comment: you can use 3d project and then use just 2 axis of game to make it "like 2D" + with camera set to orthographic

Comment: Thanks! However, I still don't know how should I slice the object... I looked at the library and example, but could not test it thoroughly. Is this library suitable or would you recommend another?